# spring boot uploading permanent files

Tags: java, spring-mvc, file-upload, spring-boot

i am trying to upload files using spring boot but each time i restart the server the files i uploaded disappear .
spring boot creates file with the name `upload-dir` and each time i restart the server this file being deleted and recreated, so i don't know where to upload and store my files.

my file upload controller code :

```
package com.theligue.webservice;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.MvcUriComponentsBuilder;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;

import com.theligue.webservice.storage.StorageFileNotFoundException;
import com.theligue.webservice.storage.StorageService;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Controller
public class FileUploadController {

    private final StorageService storageService;

    @Autowired
    public FileUploadController(StorageService storageService) {
        this.storageService = storageService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/uploadPOC")
    public String listUploadedFiles(Model model) throws IOException {
        model.addAttribute("files", storageService
                .loadAll()
                .map(path ->
                        MvcUriComponentsBuilder
                                .fromMethodName(FileUploadController.class, "serveFile", path.getFileName().toString())
                                .build().toString())
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
        return "uploadForm";
    }





    @GetMapping("/files/{filename:.+}")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> serveFile(@PathVariable String filename) {
        Resource file = storageService.loadAsResource(filename);
        return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\""+file.getFilename()+"\"")
                .body(file);
    }

    @PostMapping("/")
    public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                                   RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        storageService.store(file); 
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message",
                "You successfully uploaded " + file.getOriginalFilename() + "!");

        return "redirect:/uploadPOC/";
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(StorageFileNotFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity handleStorageFileNotFound(StorageFileNotFoundException exc) {
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are using the spring boot example? So you just need to remove in the Application.init() the storageService.deleteAll() call, which deletes all uploaded files on startup.

Comment: thank you that worked , do you know how to upload files to a directory different that what in the example ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are MYSQL Database to upload your files, I would like you to try the following method.
Under your WEB-INF folder you should have spring-servlet file. In that file you would have defined hibernate properties. It should be like the following code.

```
<property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect"> org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
```

when you keep your property as "create" then everytime you start your server it is bound to recreate the table and upload the file again and again. In order to save new files into the database while keeping the old ones intact do the following.

Replace

```
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
```

with

```
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
```

That's it. Now instead of recreation of the table there will be updation of files in your database.